# vitamio unable to play udp streaming in android

Tags: android, udp, video-streaming, vitamio

I am using [vitamio](https://www.vitamio.org/en/) library to play video streaming in android . Though I can play `rtsp` streaming with it, but I can't play `udp` streaming .

I integrated vitamio via gradle

```
compile 'me.neavo:vitamio:4.2.2'
```

And using it on activity like following

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (!io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this)) //it will check the include library of Vitamio
            return;

        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        Vitamio.initialize(this);
        mVideoView.setVideoPath("udp://@192.168.0.104:1234");
        //mVideoView.setVideoPath("rtsp://192.168.0.104:8554/ss");
        mVideoView.setVideoQuality(MediaPlayer.VIDEOQUALITY_HIGH);
        mVideoView.setBufferSize(2048);
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        mVideoView.start();
        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
            }


        });
        mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Here is my code for layout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="me.example.vitamiotest.MainActivity">

    <io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried chaning url to `udp://@192.168.0.104:1234` (removing @) with no luck . rtsp streaming is playing well .

Here is one thing to be noted that those streaming aren't actually live streaming in some remote url . I am streaming from my PC using `vlc`  and `192.168.0.104` is my PC's local ip .In case of `rtsp` I can play `rtsp://192.168.0.104:8554/ss` this url but for `udp` nothing worked, no error msg in the log .

Comment: Hi Mithun, did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: no , later switched to VLC

Comment: you used vlc for android in your app?

Comment: @CuriousMind yes

Comment: @MithunSarkerShuvro - thanks I did the same and it works perfectly.

Comment: @MithunSarkerShuvro Hi, I use vlc too, but I have a problem.. could you help me?... after a time video freeze and audio is okay.. do you know how make it right?

Answer (score 0):

try this udp stream on your Pc or use other SoftWare;
in my app,udp steam is playing right.

`mVideoView.setVideoPath("udp://@238.0.0.1:1234");`

Comment: Can you provide some code for this to work? I am using something similar to the question and ain´t got errors but still no dice...